# error Command failed with signal "SIGKILL" on fargate

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a fargate cluster running a node.js API, running on fargate 1.4.0
I have maybe 8-25 instances running depending on the load. Instances are defined with these parameters using aws CDK:

```
cpu: 512,
assignPublicIp: true,
memoryLimitMiB: 2048,
publicLoadBalancer: true,
```

Like few times a day I get error like this:

> error Command failed with signal "SIGKILL".

I thought I was running out of memory, so I've configured node, to start with less memory like this: `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=900`
This made it less likely to occur, but I am still getting some SIGKILLs.
When looking at the instances at runtime I see they have plenty of memory free on the OS level:

```json
{
  "freemem": "6.95GB",
  "totalmem": "7.79GB",
  "max_old_space_size": 813.1680679321289,
  "processUptime": "46m",
  "osUptime": "49m",
  "rssMemory": "396.89MB"
}
```

Why is fargate still killing those instances? Is there a way to find out most memory hungry processes just before the SIGKILL?

Comment: You aren't using Fargate Spot are you?

Comment: No, I have launch type as `FARGATE`